# Beginning Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've read a couple of Related questions by the site, but can't find what I'm looking for.

After having done normal PHP without much extra(by which I mean a templating system) for a year now, I feel like trying Zend. Simply because it's the biggest name. I wanna try CakePHP too later.

I've been looking into the examples, but these are all inline-code examples.
In learning PHP, I've used a template system, in order to keep the PHP and the HTML completely separated. Is this possible with the Zend Framework, or should I use a template system alongside it?

Also, what's the deal with executing several .bat files? Is there really so much work in setting up folder-structures with the correct files in them should you did it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework is a quite good solution to use as separate modules or complete package as well. You can use only it's templater system (but it's not so super) or you can put on a whole system using Zend_Application, Zend_Controller, Zend_Db, Zend_View, etc.

The .bat (or .sh) file is for the Zend_Tool. It's an experimental command line tool to build modules and applications easier.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use zend's built in template solution that comes with Zend View, roll your own, or even integrate something like Smarty. At the end of day, its your call. Zend is fairly flexible in terms of which of its component you want to use and which you don't.

Answer (score 0):

frankly for me these components do the most of work and i dont think i will need more than

(Zend_view , Zend layout , Zend navigation ,Zend breadcrumb)

it's most likely to keep the PHP and the HTML completely separated

about zend tool : its just tool to make Zend development much easier

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you take a look at the online tutorial found [here](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/367-Example-Zend-Framework-Blog-Application-Tutorial-Parts-1-8-Revisited.html).  It's a step by step walk through the framework showing you the basics of how you'd build a small Zend Framework app, and shows you how to integrate things like access control, interface with the database, etc.  It's written in really understandable language with great source code included.

As for the batch files, you may want to download a demo copy of Zend Studio.  It allows you to create a ZF project and does all of the setup for you without requiring you to mess with the command line.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you must first understand the basic directory tree of Zend Framework including all setup needed and familiarization with bootstrapping and setting configurations with a .ini file.